# count same items in comma separated string in sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

Hi i have comma seperated id's in database. 
I want to count/percentage them individually (GROUP BY) and wanna make pie chart. How to do it ?

Like, Example database picture is attached.

```
Id         COUNT
1-----------6 OR some%
15----------3 OR some%
17----------2 OR some%
2-----------2 OR some%
6-----------2 OR some%
12----------1 OR some%
```

[image: Database records (Example)]

Comment: What have you tried? Provide code sample.

Comment: Fix your data model so it has a reasonable structure.  Storing numbers in strings is the wrong approach.  Storing ids is even worse because you cannot define foreign key relationships.

Comment: I have no idea how to try it. Need sql help

Comment: YOu can acheive by php only not by mysql

Comment: @VijaySharma get them all and then explode and then count ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

suppose you got data in `$result`
 then

```
$result['count']=count(explode(",",$result['column_name']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside the fact that your DB structure is a total mess you can try the following:

```
$arrData = [
    "1","15,17","1","1","15,17","1","1","1,2","6,7,12,16","9,10","2,4,6,7","14,15,16"
];

$arrCounts = [];

array_walk($arrData, function($item, $key) use (&$arrCounts)    {
    foreach(explode(",",$item) AS $val)
    {
        if (!isset($arrCounts[$val]))   $arrCounts[$val] = 0;
        $arrCounts[$val]++;
    }
});
ksort($arrCounts);
print_r($arrCounts);
```

Answer (score -1):

Convert the variable containing the numbers seperated by a comma to an array with explode(), and count the items of the array.

```
$string = '1,2,3,4';
$array = explode(',',$string);
echo "String contains ".count($array)." items";
```

Comment: Your answer is wrong it gives total no of items instead of each item count.

Comment: @AnandPandey It is not wrong. The OP wanted a way to count items in a comma seperated string and this is how to do it. It should be self explanatory that you would need to loop through your rows first.